# Category Search in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm using magento 1.9. I'm trying to implement category search. My form is simple checkbox where users can enter categories they want with comma separated values and the next page will display products of both category (OR condition). 
Currently default catalog search will display all products have category name is any of their attributes.
I googled a lot but did not find any proper solution for my problem. Is there any built in script which I can use? Or any function in catalogsearch module I should edit to make it work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple category searches does not work in default Magento. But, you can always use single category search using the below-mentioned code

```
www.domain.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=abc&catid=1
```

in URL

Comment: Hi Abhinav, thank you for the suggestion. But I wrote a script to get products from categories.